# Is this a typo in Jech's Set Theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In **Jech's Set Theory, p. 603** in the chapter about Proper Forcing, the proof of Theorem 31.7. In the second but last paragraph, the proof says

> By Theorem 8.27 (Menas), $\lbrace M \cap \lambda \colon N \in C \rbrace$ contains a club set in $[\lambda]^{\omega}$ and hence there exists some $M \in C$ with $M \cap \lambda \in S$.

My question is, is the $N \in C$ as mentioned inside the set, really a new set $N$ or maybe even a typo? I cannot see where this set $N$ comes from as it is not defined at any point and also not appearing elsewhere.

Comment: I agree that $\{M\cap\lambda:M\in C\}$ makes more sense that $\{M\cap\lambda:N\in C$. The math here is way over my head, so let me ask you: (1) Does $\{M\cap\lambda:M\in C\}$ contain a club set in $[\lambda]^\omega$ (whatever that means)? (2) If so, does the fact that it contains a club set follow from Theorem 8.27 (whatever that might be)? (3) Does the fact (if such it be) that $\{M\cap\lambda:M\in C\}$ contains a club set imply the existence of $M\in C$ with $M\cap\lambda\in S$? If all three answers are yes, you've probably found and corrected a typo.

Comment: In short, why don't you just **assume** that $N$ was supposed to be $M$ and see if it all makes sense that way?

Comment: I agree with bof, this is clearly a typo and that $N$ should be an $M$. The set under consideration is just the projection of the club $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, clearly a typo. I checked it and it was also verified by Jech himself.